# string splitting. Finding the right way to do it

Tags: c#, string, split

Im in need of some advice here to understand the cleanest way to split a string.

the string ix like this: `00h00m00s` although the nrs in front of the h can also be 3 or 4 like `000h00m00s`.

So i think that i can do this with a normal string.split and take of the last 3 to string 1, and do this 3 times. (and after that remove the last one to only keep the nr's)

Or would this be a cleaner (better) way if i would use Regex or something ?
Im still in the learning period of the coding, and would like to know what you think of such a case. What way is the better way to do, and why ?

Comment: What is it? a Date? How about DateTime.Parse() or ParseExact?

Comment: Regex will be the cleaner way to do this and this is a nice way to learn Regex which is very powerful tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your input matches the format `#h#m#s` where `#` stands for one or more decimal digits, you can use the [String.Split Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) to split the input into four parts, the [Int32.Parse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx) to parse each of the first three parts to an integer, and the [TimeSpan Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) to represent the result:

```
var parts = "123h45m07s".Split('h', 'm', 's');

// parts == { "123", "45", "07", "" }

var result = new TimeSpan(hours:   int.Parse(parts[0]),
                          minutes: int.Parse(parts[1]),
                          seconds: int.Parse(parts[2]));

// result == {5.03:45:07}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this, a Regex would probably be best -- it's a well-defined format.

```
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"^(\d+)h(\d+)m(\d+)s$");
var hoursString = match.Groups[1].Value;
var minutesString = match.Groups[2].Value;
var secondsString = match.Groups[3].Value;
```

Comment: although putting this in gives "unreconized escape sequence"

Comment: @Dante1986, thanks -- my bad, I forgot to escape the backslashes in the string. Fixed it by changing to an `@`-string.

Answer (score 1):

```
var fields = input.Split(new[] { "h", "m" , "s" },
                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx)  regex method:

```
public static string[] Split(
    string input,
    string pattern
)

var result = Regex.Split(input, @"\D");
```

Comment: That would discard the digits and return just the "h", "m", and "s". I doubt that's what OP is after. Were you going for `\D`?

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are suited for this task:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^(?<hours>\d+)h(?<minutes>\d+)m(?<seconds>\d+)s$");
var match = regex.Match("13h44m52s");
if (match.Success) {
  var hours = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["hours"].Value);
  var minutes = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["minutes"].Value);
  var seconds = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["seconds"].Value);
  var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds);
  // Use timeSpan ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this regex to ensure the number of digits you expect

```
var match = Regex.Match(input, "^(\d{2,})h(\d{2})m(\d{2})s$");
var h = match.Groups[1];
var m = match.Groups[2];
var s = match.Groups[3];
```